# Mobile phone project not opening Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I just downloaded one sample from this link :-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=VS.92%29.aspx

But when i try to run in my Visual Studio 2010 i get some error as `This type of project is not supported in Visual Studio 2010`

Why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you downloaded and installed the Windows Phone 7 SDK?

http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7/